# Openbox: Way to assign multiple possible keys to same action?

Tags: openbox

I have set up some keyboard shortcut to organize my windows:

```
<keybind key="W-A-Left">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <!-- <action name="MaximizeVert"/> -->
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <height>100%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-A-Up">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <height>50%</height>
    <width>100%</width>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-A-Right">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <!-- <action name="MaximizeVert"/> -->
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <height>100%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-A-Down">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <!-- <action name="MaximizeVert"/> -->
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <height>50%</height>
    <width>100%</width>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Now, I want to also use the numeric pad for the same actions. Currently, I copy pasted the same bloc, and replaced Left/Right/Up/Down by KP_4/8/6/2.

While that work, that feels ugly as hell, is there any way to directly tell that for either `W-S-Left` or `W-S-KP_4`, I want to do this action?

Answer (score 0):

Simply list multiple keybindings in the key field, space-separated, e.g.

```
<keybind key="W-A-Left W-S-KP_4">
    ...
</keybind>
```